# Store OpenID users into my DB like Stackoverflow does

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, openid

I have made a login system using OpenID using the following code:

```
<rp:OpenIdLogin
    runat="server"
    Identifier="https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id"
    Visible="true"
    ExampleUrl=""
    LabelText=" "
    RegisterText="Register"
    ExamplePrefix=" "
    ID="OpenIdLogin1"
    OnLoggedIn="OpenIdTextBox1_LoggedIn"
    RequestEmail="Require"
    RequestPostalCode="Request">
</rp:OpenIdLogin>
```

It takes the user to Google for authentication. I only want to store the user information like email, full name and sex in my DB.

I have written the following code to retrive email from Google but nothing is returned:

```
Imports System
Imports DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.Extensions.AttributeExchange
Partial Class Food
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If (Session("FetchResponse") Is Nothing) Then
            Return
        End If
        Dim fetchResponse As FetchResponse = CType(Session("FetchResponse"), FetchResponse)
        Email = fetchResponse.GetAttributeValue(WellKnownAttributes.Contact.Email)
    End Sub

    Public Property Email() As String
        Get

        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)

        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: My question is that when user is authenticated from google and return to my web page then the information of user like email First name lastname etc should be saved to my DB

Comment: Anyone please give answer to my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Open Id you can ask for certain information from the Service provider.So when it came back once user has authorize themself you can get the information being provided by OpenId service provider.

One of the good way to ask for additional information is to use Attribute exchange.

see here for details how you can make use of Attribute exchange for Google

[Google OpenId and Attribute Exchange](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OpenID.html#Parameters)

Once you have those parameters being send back by Google all you need to extract them from the Request and save them in the DB for future use

OpenID protocol will share certain information of user so you have to make sure if this fit in to your system or not.

Comment: can u please share a piece of code to get detail from service provider and on which page this code will be written